# OnTriggerEnter2D and OnTriggerExit2D called mutiples time

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I have one Player with `RigidBody2D` and a pillar with `BoxCollider2D`.

I check when `OnTriggerEnter2D` is called ( Player collided with the pillar ) then I try to keep Player position by change his `bodyType` to `Static`.

When `OnTriggerExit2D` is called, Player `bodyType` will be reverted to `Dynamic` again.

My problem is: after change player `bodyType` to `Static` , `OnTriggerExit2D` is called immediately. And after reverted to `Dynamic`, then `OnTriggerEnter2D` is called immediately. It goes on repeating again and again.

This is my Player and pillar

[image]

If you have any suggest please tell me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `RigidbodyType2D.Static` docs:

> **Static behaviour stops the Rigidbody2D from reacting to gravity or
>   applied forces including contacts with any other Rigidbody2D.**
>
> This type of Rigidbody2D should never repositioned explicitly. It is
>   designed to never move.
>
> A static Rigidbody2D will only collide with a dynamic Rigidbody2D body
>   type. The exception to this is if Rigidbody2D.useFullKinematicContacts
>   is set to true in which case it will also collide with any
>   [[Kinematic]] body types.
>
> When an attached Collider2D is set to trigger, it will always produce
>   a trigger for any Collider2D attached to [[Dynamic]] or [[Kinematic]]
>   body types.

That's why the exit is triggered again, if you want your character to sticks to the wall you should do a different approach.

Comment: Thank you for you comment , Do you have any approach to stick Player to the wall ?

Comment: You're welcome,if you consider this answer as "Correct" mark it please. About your second question: There are many approaches, some of them are simpler than others, like changing gravityScale to 0. But generally will depend on how you control your character movement, etc

Comment: Thank you for your help , I will try to use gravityScale .

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this issue is changed to use constraints.
The way I approached it was to freeze the X and Y positions as well as the Z rotation whenever OnCollisionEnter() was triggered.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collison){
     if(collison.transform.tag -= "Player"){
             body.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionY | RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionX | RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;
     } 
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision){
     if(collision.transform.tag == "Player"){
         body.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.None;
     }
 }
```